# Is it possible to refresh the contents of "Show Table Data" without closing and re-opening again?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Changes to the data are not updated immediately. It is required to close the query results window and then re-open it again to see the changes. Is it possible to refresh the data without reopening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intial generated query for "Show Table Data" is simply "SELECT * FROM Mytable".

After selecting the "Show Table Data" option, you are now seeing that query's results in the new grid-type window.

You can change the SQL syntax for that basic query by looking for the VERY SMALL "SQL" icon that hopefully appeared on your toolbar, or to simply re-execute the existing query, hit the slightly more obvious "Red exclamtion-mark" on the same toolbar. [image: execute sql icon]

For reference, this toolbar is called "Query Designer" and *should* automagically appear when viewing the grid-type SQL data .. it is always there for me, but perhaps you have "lost or moved it" out of view, in which case re-enable as normal.